# FusionCharts in Android?

Tags: android, fusioncharts, android-browser

I have been trying to get the Fusion Charts to work on Android 2.2 (emulator). But its not loading anything . i can see only blank screen.

Has anyone run Fusion Charts on the Android device / emulator before? Can Fusion charts run on Android itself?

Edit:

I have try to load the chart in default browser of android. In that also its not loading. But its running in Opera and Mozilla Firefox. Any Idea?

Additional Information :  Browser version is Webkit 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FusionCharts Flash version loads fine on devices supporting Flash (Glaxy Tab, etc.)

For JavaScript version, the story is slightly different. I am copying a section of my notes here:

---

1. FusionCharts uses an enhanced version of HighCharts in order to render JavaScript based charts.
2. HighCharts uses 'SVG' as a technology to render the visualizations. Though considered part of HTML5, certain mobile platforms (like Android) does not support SVG as of yet.
3. As of now, Android supports "canvas" as a drawing technology for HTML5. Gingerbread is expected to fully support SVG.

If you refer to the history of HighCharts, you would see that HighCharts version 1.x supported canvas, but since 2.x they have shifted to SVG anticipating the inclusion of SVG support on major mobile platforms.

We, at FusionCharts, use HighCharts 2.x as a base to render FusionCharts. Consequently, they do not run on Android.

However, there is a workaround, if you replace the highcharts.js (2.x) supplied with FusionCharts by older highcharts.js, you would notice that it works fine on Android platforms. But that would mean limited functionality as a lot of enhancements done to HighCharts would be lost.

I hope I had been clear on my points. If you need further clarification, I can definitely provide you with more information. I can also assist you in implementing the older highcharts.js by particularly detecting Android based browsers and doing selective loading of older HighCharts JS files.

There is also a small extension of FusionCharts that gracefully handles this replacement of older HighCharts for devices that does not support SVG or VML but supports canvas.

You can see it in action at: http://www.fusioncharts.com/labs/peek/canvasmodulefallback/

Download the files from: http://www.fusioncharts.com/labs/peek/canvasmodulefallback/sample-canvasmodulefallback.zip

Comment: This works on my HTC Thunderbolt and on my desktop in Chrome IE and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Zero when the data will be mobile devices crash.

```
    var chartObj1 = new FusionCharts({
        swfUrl:'Charts/Column2D.swf',

        renderer: 'javascript',
        renderAt: 'chartspan',

        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption" : "Sales Summary",
                "subcaption": "Summary of Sales"
            },
            "data": [
                {"value":"0"},
                {"value":"0"},
                {"value":"0"},
                {"value":"0"}
            ]
        },
        dataFormat: FusionChartsDataFormats.JSON
    }).render();
```

Comment: which package has FusionCharts methos? do we need to install any package?