# Fusion charts in android

Tags: android, fusioncharts

I am making an app in which i have to use fusion charts to represent some data so anyone can help me in how to do this

`edit` : Can you please tell me how to use google charts AND fussion charts in android

Comment: possible duplicate of [FusionCharts in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894107/fusioncharts-in-android)

Comment: i want to edit my question ..                                             Can you please tell me how to use google charts AND fussion charts in android . Please tell me how to use BOTH.Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can try once the sample application from  [PhoneGap API to query call-logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277250/phonegap-api-to-query-call-logs) which I created using FusionCharts and PhoneGap. The charts came fine in  my application.

In case you are not comfortable using PhoneGap, you can also use WebView object. However, you need to make sure to enable a few settings like:

You might need to enable JavaScript and plugins for the WebView:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I Used fusion chart and prepare a chart by it and now the question arises how to use that chart code in webview in android ..               The Code is as follows:-

Comment: <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://fusioncharts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusioncharts.xml&amp;up_ct=Column3D&amp;up_c=Weekly%20Sales&amp;up_sc=Comparison&amp;up_xt=Week&amp;up_yt=Sales&amp;up_sn=&amp;up_l=Week%201%3BWeek%202%3BWeek%203%3BWeek%204&amp;up_cc=&amp;up_v=40900%3B31400%3B26700%3B5540&amp;up_t=&amp;up_bA=1&amp;up_bSLb=1&amp;up_bSV=1&amp;up_bSLm=1&amp;up_bSLg=1&amp;up_bRL=1&amp;up_bFN=1&amp;up_bFS=1&amp;up_bTT=1&amp;up_np=%24&amp=0&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=480&amp;title=Shopkeepers_Point&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>

Comment: This seems to be the Google Gadget and this is from internet. So, it seems that you would first need to allow internet access to your  application. Then if you pass the whole URL to the WebView using webview.loadUrl("google URL here") it might work.

Comment: I will try to do that. Recently I have upgrade my mac to Lion and I need to re install a few things. Once I setup these I will try to provide a sample.