# android:fusion charts shows nothing

Tags: android, fusioncharts

I am making an app in which i am using fusion charts and when i use   "file:///android_asset/www/indexx.html" (which contains html and js code) and when it loads it shows page with no image and white background means no chart is displayed.Can anyone help me in this.Any help will be appreciated.Can anyone help step by step method to implement fusion charts.I have read the given page of stack overflow   [FusionCharts in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894107/fusioncharts-in-android) but it couldnt help me.
Thanks.

Comment: yes i do have it installed on my device

Comment: it'd be helpful if you show your code and we can see the implementation you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put all the .js files(FusionCharts.js, FusionCharts.HC.js, FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js, and jquery.min.js) in the asset or www folder?
because generally in Web Apps when .js files are missing or the Path error is there at that time this problem arises.
Please share a code snippet!